# How to create an acl in squid to filter based on content length

Tags: squid

The reply_body_max_size in Squid checks for the content length of the reply and if it is greater than the specified size it throws an error to the user.

I don't want to show an error page if this exceeds the limit.
Is there any way or any workaround in Squid to create an acl or something similar to filter based on their content length ?

Something similar to the following

if ( content_size > 15MB )
{
     // do this;
}
else
{
    // do this;
}

Comment: What do you want to do if the content is >15Mb ? Similarly < 15Mb ?

Comment: @lain In Squid I am using "tcp_outgoing_address" directive to change the source address based on a acl which currently checks for URL with .exe, .iso extension and then redirect the request through a different ISP link using source based IP routing. This works perfectly fine. If I am able to filter content >15Mb using some acl or any other method I would like to use it with "tcp_outgoing_address" in the similar way.

Answer (score 0):

Check this [reply_body_max_size directive](http://www.squid-cache.org/Doc/config/reply_body_max_size/)

Comment: I have already checked the reply_body_max_size directive, using it I am able to filter traffic >15MB, but it shows an error page to the user which I don't want. I want to use it with tcp_outgoing_address similar like an acl. Any idea on how to do it ?